# typescript: object assignment do not work as expect

Tags: typescript, types

```
type A = {
    name: string
}
const a = { name: '', x: 12 }
const aa: A = a //no error
```

However:

```
type A = {
    name: string
}
const aa: A = { name: '', x: 12 } // error ts2322
```

The two snippets have exactly the same meaning in js, why the first is valid ts code while the second not?

It looks a lot like a ts bug, but I can not get any hint after searching the internet

Answer (score 0):

OK，ts treated literal and variable differently, while it is no different from a js prespective

Answer (score 0):

In the following assignment:

```
const a = { name: '', x: 12 }
```

The type of `a` should be structurally-inferred from the value it has been assigned (i.e. equivalent to `{ name: string; x: number; }`).

So for the subsequent assignment:

```
const aa: A = a
```

I believe the TypeScript compiler accepts this because the structurally-inferred type satisfies the `A` type (i.e. it has all the properties required by the `A` type, despite having an excess `x: number`).

I suspect the compiler isn't as lenient with the second snippet because you cannot initialise with a property that doesn't belong in type `A`.

Comment: I need the official doc covering this,  your answer is help though...

Comment: See ["Excess Property Checks"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks), I think it'll help your understanding about this matter.